# Redirect root to a subdirectory then remove it from url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I redirected the root url (`example.com`) to its subdirectory (`example.com/subdir`) and now I want to remove the subdirectory name from the url as below:

I want

```
example.com/subdir
```

to be rewritten to

```
example.com
```

with the condition that other files and subdirectories don't get rewritten.
the current root htaccess is this (wordpress rules):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**EDIT**

For redirecting I used yoast seo plugin tools but I can change it to other approaches.

Comment: Please post the rules you are using to redirect your root URIs to the subdirectory .

Comment: @starkeen please see edit.